# Loop if a user enters a blank

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with a while loop.I have gotten everything to work except that if the user enters a blank for a phrase it gives them a statement saying to enter a non-blank phrase. And this needs to loop until the user enters a phrase but i can't seem to get it to work.

This is the code :

```
System.out.print("Enter a phrase to search the above text for: ");
phrase = kb.nextLine();

while (phrase.equals(""))
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a non-blank phrase: ");
    phrase = kb.next();
}
```

Comment: @FdFehfhd.. You need to mark an answer as accepted, by clicking the arrow besides each answer. See [**How to accept an answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: `but i can't seem to get it to work` - next time please specify __how__ you can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your while loop, you are using `phrase = kb.next();`, which will read the `newline` when a blank input is given. You can use `kb.nextLine();` to ignore the newline from the blank input.

```
        while (phrase.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a non-blank phrase: ");
            phrase = kb.nextLine();
        }
```

Or you can use `trim` to remove trailing `newline`, so use `while (phrase.trim().equals(""))`: -

```
       while (phrase.trim().equals(""))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a non-blank phrase: ");
            phrase = kb.next();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with trim:

```
            while (phrase.trim().equals(""))
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter a non-blank phrase: ");
                phrase = kb.next();
            }
```